How to initialize a unique pointer with a struct?
This code:
int main()
{
    struct test
    {
        std::string s;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<struct test> p = nullptr;

    p = std::make_unique<struct test>("test");

    printf("%s\n", p->s);
}

gives me a compile error:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/14/memory:78,
                 from struct-pointer.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/14/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘std::__detail::__unique_ptr_t<_Tp> std::make_unique(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = main()::test; _Args = {const char (&)[5]}; __detail::__unique_ptr_t<_Tp> = __detail::__unique_ptr_t<main()::test>]’:
struct-pointer.cc:13:38:   required from here
   13 |     p = std::make_unique<struct test>("test");
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/14/bits/unique_ptr.h:1076:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘main()::test::test(const char [5])’
 1076 |     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
struct-pointer.cc:6:12: note: candidate: ‘main()::test::test()’
    6 |     struct test
      |            ^~~~
struct-pointer.cc:6:12: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
struct-pointer.cc:6:12: note: candidate: ‘main()::test::test(const main()::test&)’
struct-pointer.cc:6:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char [5]’ to ‘const main()::test&’
struct-pointer.cc:6:12: note: candidate: ‘main()::test::test(main()::test&&)’
struct-pointer.cc:6:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char [5]’ to ‘main()::test&&’

Seems like it expects my struct test to have a constructor. However, I saw plenty of examples, where the struct was initialized without a constructor, like this one:
struct test foo = { "test" };

This compiles, but apparently struct test wasn't initialized properly:
printf("%s\n", foo.s);

produces garbage, instead of "test".
Two questions: How to properly initialyze the struct such that the printf statement produces "test"?
And how to initialyze struct test when using a unique_ptr instead of a local variable?

It's not a problem with unique_ptr, printf is a C functon that doesn't know anything about C++ class std::string.

Actually, you have two questions in one question :/ Initialisation is complicated topic. std::make_unique can only use aggregate initialisation since C++20. In older compilers you will need a constructor for test or to use new (std::unique_ptr p { new test {"test"} };) instead.

"Two questions:" -- Which is one more than is allowed in a question.

printf("%s\n", foo.s.c_str()); or cout << foo.s << '\n'

Side note : std::unique_ptr<struct test> p = nullptr; , use std::unique_ptr<test> p; it will already intialize itself to nullptr and the "C" style struct test syntax is not needed
